# When the UIView's `bounds` origins are increased with positive numbers, why do the subviews shift in the negative direction?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cgrect

This must be something really simple, and my basic math knowledge may be lacking. This is clear (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32033392/1498178)):

> View's frame determines its **location in superview**. View's bounds
>   determines its **subviews locations**. That means, if you change view's
>   bounds, its location won't be changed, but all of its subviews
>   location will be changed.

The view controller, after starting a Single View App:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let v1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 300))
        v1.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        let v2 = UIView(frame: v1.bounds.insetBy(dx: 50, dy: 50))
        v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        self.view.addSubview(v1)
        v1.addSubview(v2)
    }
```

Checking on the LLDB console, this is completely clear too:

```
(lldb) p v1.frame
(CGRect) $R0 = (origin = (x = 100, y = 100), size = (width = 200, height = 300))
(lldb) p v1.bounds
(CGRect) $R1 = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 200, height = 300))

(lldb) p v2.frame
(CGRect) $R2 = (origin = (x = 50, y = 50), size = (width = 100, height = 200))
(lldb) p v2.bounds
(CGRect) $R3 = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 100, height = 200))
```

[image: A red square positioned in the middle of a blue square]

Adding `v1.bounds.origin.x += 50` (or `v1.bounds.origin.x = 50` for that matter) after `v1.addSubview(v2)` results in:

```
(lldb) p v1.frame
(CGRect) $R0 = (origin = (x = 100, y = 100), size = (width = 200, height = 300))
(lldb) p v1.bounds
(CGRect) $R1 = (origin = (x = 50, y = 0), size = (width = 200, height = 300))

(lldb) p v2.frame
(CGRect) $R2 = (origin = (x = 50, y = 50), size = (width = 100, height = 200))
(lldb) p v2.bounds
(CGRect) $R3 = (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 100, height = 200))
```

The LLDB console output still fits in with my current understanding, but then this is how it is rendered:

[image: Red square lined up with the left wall of the blue square]

**Why?** Tried to reason about it (see below) and I understand that the views' coordinate systems are relative to each other, but if 50 is added to `v1`'s `origin.x`, the the subviews' effective `frame.origin` is supposed to be `(x=50+50, y=0)`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found a satisfying answer in Matt Neuburg's [Programming iOS 11 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491999225) with a similar example:

```
/* ... */
let v2 = UIView(frame:v1.bounds.insetBy(dx: 10, dy: 10))
/* ... */
v1.bounds.origin.x += 10
v1.bounds.origin.y += 10
```

> Nothing happens to the superview’s size or position. But the subview
>   has moved up and to the left so that it is flush with its superview’s
>   top-left corner. Basically, what we’ve done is to say to the
>   superview, **“Instead of calling the point at your upper left
>   (0.0,0.0), call that point (10.0,10.0).”** Because the subview’s frame
>   origin is itself at (10.0,10.0), the subview now touches the
>   superview’s top-left corner. The effect of changing a view’s bounds
>   origin may seem directionally backward — we increased the superview’s
>   origin in the positive direction, but the subview moved in the
>   negative direction — but think of it this way: a view’s bounds origin
>   point coincides with its frame’s top left.

Therefore it seems modifying the `origin` is more like a mapping operation than a coordinate system transformation. This would also explain why the results are the same for `+= 50` and `= 50`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By adjusting the *bounds'* origin.x of v1, you are expanding the origin beyond the visible rectangle. (This is how a UIScrollView works.)

If you instead modify the *frame's* origin.x, you will, I believe, see results more in line with your expectations.